# Prove there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $P(X-y\in A) > \delta$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be independent real random variables. Let $\delta \geq0 $ and $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose $P(X-Y \in A) > \delta$.

Prove there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $P(X-y\in A) > \delta$.

---

I have tried writing it a bit out:
$$\delta < P(X-Y \in A) = \mathbb{E}[1_{A}(X-Y)] = \int_AX-y \ P_Y(dy),$$
but I can't really see where to go from here (and if this is even the best approach). The book I am reading just says it follows from Fubini's Theorem. Can someone help me see that?

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the marginals. Hence, Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem is applicable and we get $\delta <P(X-Y \in A)=\int \int I_{\{(x,y): x-y \in A\}} d(F_X\times F_Y) (x,y)=\int P(X-y \in A)dF_Y(y)$. Now suppose $P(X-y \in A) \leq \delta$ for all $y$. Then we get the contradiction $\delta <\int P(X-y \in A)dF_Y(y) \leq \int \delta dF_Y(y)=\delta$.

Comment: I am still not quite sure how and why you are using Fubini... Can you eloborate a bit more?

Comment: @Jacobiman I have inserted one more step in the proof. I hope it is clear now.